# Angular 2/4 display image based on extension in a row

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Hi I have following code to display images.

```
<div  *ngFor="let image of images" >
   <span *ngIf="    ">  //if img=t.jpg display this line
  <label>JPEG Image</label><img src='{{image.img}}'/>
   </span>
      <span *ngIf="    "> // if img=t.jpg dont display this line
  <label>PNG Image</label><img src='{{image.img}}'/>
   </span>
</div>
```

I want to put condition that if image extension is .jpg i.e image.jpg I want JPEG line to display, if it is .png i.e. image.png I want PNG Image line to display.
Please let me know how can I read the extension of the image/file in *ngIf
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Here is the sample code please check it
>
> [StackBitz url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-extension)

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
   images = [
    {
      img: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_100.jpg',
    },
    {
      img: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/fantendo/images/6/6e/Small-mario.png',
    }
  ];
  public getExstendsion(image) {
    if (image.endsWith('jpg') || image.endsWith('jpeg')) {
      return 'jpg';
    }
    if (image.endsWith('png')) {
      return 'png';
    }
  }
}
```

**Html**

```
 <div  *ngFor="let image of images" >
  
   <span *ngIf="(getExstendsion(image.img) == 'jpg') || getExstendsion(image.img) == 'jpeg'"> 
  <label>JPEG Image</label><img src='{{image.img}}'/>
   </span>
      <span *ngIf="getExstendsion(image.img) == 'png'"> 
  <label>PNG Image</label><img src='{{image.img}}'/>
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `image.img` contains a string:

**typescript**

```
// this checks if it ends with .jpg or .jpeg and returns true if so
func isJPG(name) {
  return name.endsWith('jpg') || name.endsWith('jpeg')
}
// same, but for png
func isPNG(name)
  return name.endsWith('png')
}
```

**html template**

`*ngIf="isJPG(image.img)"`

note: typing from memory, so apologies if my function syntax is off. General idea should still work. Create a method, use `endsWith()` method to check string, apply method in template on `*ngIf=`